# Detecting when a Picture Box touches another control

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a game where the player controls a square, whenever it hits a wall it is supposed to die. The Square is a Picture Box and the walls are picture boxes too. You can move using W,A,S and D. I was thinking about doing something similar to:

```
if(Square.Top == Square.Top + Square.Height)
```

and then restart the game. Is there any better way doing it? Istead of having alot of IFs? Whenever a control touches another to do something?

Thanks alot !

Comment: actually, `Square.Top == Wall.Top` does not indicate that they touch, unless the wall is above the Square. if the wall is to the right or left of the square, they are not touching even the top is the same.

Comment: It was just an example, let me correct myself Square.Top == Wall.Square.Top + Square.Height

Comment: Collision detection is largely blogged about on the internet. A quick search gave me this article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection but really, there are tons of blog posts on this topic.

Comment: Thanks Pedro ! I will check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you get the control's containing rectangle by [`Control.Bounds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bounds(v=vs.110).aspx), and then use [`IntersectsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith(v=vs.110).aspx) with another rectangle.

```
if(Square.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Wall.Bounds))
{
    // ...
}
```

Keep in mind that it won't trigger when your square touches a wall, only when it starts going on top of it, but I assume that's what you want.